# Redirecting “.htaccess” with same folder & file name

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

A while ago I rebuilt a site that was on a CMS. As expected the Google search console regularly comes up with URLs that generate 404 crawling errors which I would promptly redirect to their new equivalents using a 301 on a `.htaccess` file.

The issue is that I came across the URL of an old page which looked like this:

```
http://www.example.com/example
```

The new page is now called `http://www.example.com/example.php`.

There is, however, a folder called `example` too so if I add a redirect like this:

```
Redirect 301 /example http://www.example.com/example.php
```

everything in that folder also gets redirected, so a URL called `http://www.example.com/example/product.php` would now show up as `http://www.example.com/example.php/product.php`.

Is there a way to redirect the old URL successfully without having to rename the folder `example`?

Comment: It is unclear on what the problem is.

Comment: My apologies. There is an old link to a page called /example (just a page not a folder) that needs to be redirected to /example.php. There is also a new folder called /example so the URL http://www.example.com/example now causes a 403 Forbidden error. How do I redirect this URL which used to be just a page to the new page /example.php without causing problems with the contents of the new folder /example and without having to rename the said new folder.

Comment: You can just use `RedirectMatch 301 ^/example/?$ /example.php` and test it after clearing your browser cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please clear your browser cache and then put the following code at main root `.htaccess` file :

```
DirectorySlash Off 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+example [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)  /$1.php [R=302,L]
```

The code above will stop `directoryslash` and make it `off` so no file without slash goes to be directory as default and then check if `example` exists in `QUERY_STRING` and the trick comes here in this line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f`,it will check if adding `.php` to this string , is that really file in directory or not ? and already we have `example.php` in root so , it will go to last line to redirect any string that passed the rules above to `itself.php` and that what you want exactly.

The above code will catch any `example` in only `root` directory with `example` only but if wanna inherit other sub-folders or apply this rule to entire site  so , whenever there is string without extension the priority will be for the file , put the following code at your main root `.htaccess`  file :

```
DirectorySlash Off 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)  /$1.php [R=302,L]
```

After testing this code , if it is Ok , change `302` to `301` to be permanent redirection

Comment: glad to help , wish you all the best