# How to assign a page to a subpage

Tags: php, .htaccess

for example, i have something like this:

[image]

I need result like this:

```
../jobs/designer.php

../jobs/developer.php

../jobs.php
```

I have `.htaccess` to remove .php from url

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Is this possible with `.htaccess`?

Comment: Is there anything in particular that prevents you to change the structure of your project and simply add a folder called "jobs"?

Comment: @El_Vanja I tried it, but if i come to `../jobs` i see only folder structure not content of jobs.php

Comment: Must the file be called `jobs`? Seems to me that a more logical structure would be a "jobs" subfolder with an `index.php` or perhaps `list.php`. I mean, there's probably a way to do it with `.htaccess`, but the simpler things are, the cleaner the solution is.

Comment: I found solution here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433727/redirecting-htaccess-with-same-folder-file-name) but thank you for your time :)

Comment: I would recommend that you use a router instead. That's going to make it way easier to set up the URL's exactly how you want them without needing to modify the folder structure.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have no experience with router, can you recommend a guide or an article or something that will help me?

Comment: If you google on "php router" you will find many different libs. They usually have docs on how to use them. Look through a few and see which makes sense for you.